# Does spin 3/2 imply 2/3 full rotations?

Tags: quantum-spin, representation-theory, rotation

In [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin-1/2) it writes:

> ... a spin of 1/2 means that the particle must be rotated by two full
> turns (through 720°) before it has the same configuration as when it
> started.

The animation in the page demonstrates this statement (I think it is an analogy tough).

So the question is does a spin of 3/2 imply a turn of 240 degrees with the same approach?

In [another Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_(physics)#Higher_spins) the mathematical expression of higher spins are given, but they look quite complicated. It would be very nice if you could explain these expressions and their physical meanings as simple as possible. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/597902/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic The difference is the guy has some idea about the matrix notation of the concept.

Comment: well... I think it's a dupe of the question linked by @Qmechanic .  Can you please clarify how this does not answer your question, i.e. what's wrong with a solution using matrix notation?

Answer (score 6):

No...  Not if you are asking about the period of the rotation matrix in the quartet representation.

You [know](https://www.emis.de/journals/SIGMA/2014/084/) that for the quartet representation, $j=3/2$, rotations, the group element is a 4×4 [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix),
$$
e^{i \theta (\hat{\boldsymbol{n}}\cdot\boldsymbol{J})} = I_4 \cos (\theta/2)\left(1+\tfrac{1}{2}\sin^2
(\theta/2)\right)+(2i \hat{\boldsymbol{n}}\cdot\boldsymbol{J} ~\sin (\theta/2))\left(1+\tfrac{1}{6} \sin^2 (\theta/2)
\right)
\\
\phantom{e^{i \theta (\hat{\boldsymbol{n}}\cdot\boldsymbol{J})}=}{}
+\frac{1}{2!} \bigl (2i \hat{\boldsymbol{n}}\cdot\boldsymbol{J}~\sin (\theta/2) \bigr)^2 \cos (\theta/2)+\frac {1}{3!}
\bigl (2i \hat{\boldsymbol{n}}\cdot\boldsymbol{J}~\sin (\theta/2) \bigr)^3.
 $$
whose period is 4π,  like *all* half-integral spin representations. You generalized wrong.

All even-dimensional ($2j+1$ even) representations of SU(2) have period 4π, easily read off the exponential of $J_z$.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. The spin part of the wave function is $$e^{im_z\phi} \,.$$ It is invariant under $2\pi/m_z$ rotations about the quantization axis. The rotation angle depends on $m_z $ rather than on $S$. For a quartet state with $m_z=\pm 3/2$ this implies invariance under a (multiple of) $4\pi/3=240^\text{o}$ rotation(s). This includes $4\pi$ rotations. Quartet or any other states with $m_z=\pm 1/2$ are invariant under $4\pi$ rotations.

Invariance of **all states** of the quartet are requires an angle of $4\pi$. However the OP did not state that his/her question is limited to this. Therefore the present answer is the more general one.

Comment: To the anonymous downvoters: please explain how $e^{im_S\phi}$ is not invariant under rotation by $\phi = 2\pi /m_S$. :-)